# Find a constant so that the random variable has a t-distribution.

Tags: statistics

Given a random variable $Y=\frac{c(X_1+X_2)}{\sqrt{(X_3)^2+(X_4)^2}}$, find c such that Y has a t-distribution.

Seems like I need to divide the numerator by $2$ and the denominator by $\sqrt{2}$ so $c=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Because $X_1+X_2 ~ N(0,2)$, we divide by $2$ and similarly for the denominator. Need an answer check and corrections if applicable.

Comment: Excuse me but you did not say what $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ and $X_4$ are nor how they are distributed.

Comment: @Martingalo Assume they are iid normally distributed

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a t-student distribution can be defined as:
$$t_{\nu} = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{\chi_{\nu}^2/\nu}}$$
where $Z$ is a standard normal distribution and $\chi_{\nu}^2$ is a chi-squared distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom.

Assuming $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ and $X_4$ are **independent standard normally** distributed (which you forgot to say) then on one side
$$X_1 + X_2 \sim N(0,2)$$
and hence
$$\frac{X_1+X_2}{\sqrt{2}} \sim N(0,1).$$

On the other side we have $X_3^2$, $X_4^2$ are both chi-squared distributed with 1 degree of fredom. Since they are independent the sum is also chi-squared distributed with $1+1=2$ degrees of freedom. That is
$$X_3^2 + X_4^2 \sim \chi_{2}^2.$$

So
$$t_2 = \frac{\frac{X_1+X_2}{\sqrt{2}} }{\sqrt{(X_3^2 + X_4^2)/2} }$$
is $t$-distributed with 2 degrees of freedom. Simplifying:
$$t_2 = \frac{X_1+X_2 }{\sqrt{X_3^2 + X_4^2} }$$
which corresponds to taking $c=1$.